# JSON nesting unidimensional arrays

Tags: jquery, json

Good morning.
 I have some arrays in JQuery

```
var fromarray=[]; ...
```

and I want to construct and access to a JSON nesting arrays.

```
  var intervalos= {"variables":[{

             "nombreVariables":{nombreVariables},
             "extremoInferior":{fromarray},
             "extremoSuperior":{toarray}
          }]};//intervalos
```

Is this correct?. And how can I access to one element? -->

```
['variables'][0]['nombreVariables'][0] ??
```

Thanks' in advance :)

Comment: I think what you are tring is correct. Have you face in error while accessing element in inner array ?

Comment: No thanks' everything is correct : ))